# App does not fit the size of various screens sizes

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

Good morning, I’m making an app with Flutter and to facilitate the adaptation of the UI on various devices I decided to use the library "[Responsive Sizer](https://pub.dev/packages/responsive_sizer)"

I made a closed release via Google Play Console to do betatesting. On most devices the UI is displayed correctly (I leave an example of screen made by Xiaomi Redmi Note 10 Pro) :

[Xiaomi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6Hid.jpg)

But in a particular device (Samsung J5) the graphics are not adapted :

[Samsung J5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2z6KJ.jpg)

I have configured the plugin on each page as mentioned in the documentation, and in each widget I have specified the size by specifying . h, . w and . sp in fonts. I attach some codes

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ResponsiveSizer(
      builder: (context, orientation, screenType) {
        return Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          body: Stack(children: <Widget>[
            _showForm(),
          ]),
        );
      },
    );
  }

Widget accountInfo() {
    return Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 0.0.h),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Stack(children: [
              Container(
                width: 19.0.w,
                height: 10.0.h,




                    child: Text(
                      "Hi, $myUsername",
                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontFamily: 'Oswald',
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        color: const Color(0xFF212427),
                        fontSize: 20.0.sp,
                      ),
                    )))
```

Comment: did you add responsive sizer size in texts. since according to the image the text seems to not change thus might cause the problem of overflowing

Comment: Yes, I did. I added new code in the answer

Comment: try adding the entire text widget and the image inside the FittedBox widget.

Comment: So what i have to do? Wrap every widget inside a FittedBox? In that case, what is the utility of Responsive Sizer

Comment: I dont use that package thus i don't know the proper reason for your problem. i use text widget wrapped in fitted box which is wrapped in an sizedbox or container for responsive text and I think it is more reliable than responsive sizer widget.